# Cant upload CSV using Websphere

Tags: java, rest, csv, jax-rs

I have a very simple file upload

```
<form>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">CSV</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Select File</th>
                            <td><input id="csv" name="csv" type="file" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><input id="fup" type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

and here is the ajax call

```
$("form").submit(function(evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $("#csv").prop("disabled",true);
        $("#fup").prop("disabled",true);
        $.ajax({
            url : 'api/readUpload',
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            async : true,
            cache : false,
            contentType : false,
            enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
            processData : false,
            success : function(response) {
                $('#response').html(response);
                $("img").hide();
                $("#csv").prop("disabled",false);
                $("#fup").prop("disabled",false);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

on the backend I have

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    @Path("/readUpload")
    public void uploadData(@FormParam("meta") String meta, @FormParam("csv") byte[] data) {
        //processing code
    }
```

My csv file has just one line (for testing)

```
col_name
some random text,some random text2
```

now, when i run the code i get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "col_name
 some random text,some random text2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65
)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:149)
    at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:205)
    at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:231)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.PrimitiveUtils.read(PrimitiveUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.handleParameter(InjectionUtils.jav
a:490)
    ... 41 more
```

and here is the full stacktrace

```
[WARNING ] javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toBadRequestException(SpecExceptio
ns.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toBadRequestException(ExceptionUti
ls.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.createParamConversionException(Inj
ectionUtils.java:560)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.handleParameter(InjectionUtils.jav
a:496)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.injectIntoCollectionOrArray(Inject
ionUtils.java:1009)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.createParameterObject(InjectionUti
ls.java:1082)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processFormParam(JAXRSUtils.java:966)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.createHttpParameterValue(JAXRSUtils.ja
va:874)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:834)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:786)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInIn
terceptor.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInt
erceptor.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain
.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationOb
server.java:124)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDes
tination.java:265)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.endpoint.AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.invoke(AbstractJaxRsWeb
Endpoint.java:134)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.handleRequest(IBMRestServlet.j
ava:149)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.doPost(IBMRestServlet.java:107
)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.service(IBMRestServlet.java:99
)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1
290)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.
java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.
java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilte
rManager.java:1157)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4956)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.handleRequest(WebApp31.java:5
25)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtu
alHost.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1014)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.jav
a:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.r
un(HttpDispatcherLink.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAn
dExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:359)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDis
patcherLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscriminatio
n(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(Ht
tpInboundLink.java:405)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(Http
InboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLi
nk.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscri
minators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(New
ConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueMan
ager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.j
ava:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.j
ava:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.
java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:11
42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:6
17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "col_name 
some random text,some random text2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65
)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Byte.java:149)
    at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:205)
    at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Byte.java:231)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.PrimitiveUtils.read(PrimitiveUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.handleParameter(InjectionUtils.jav
a:490)
    ... 41 more
```

1. is this the proper way to read csv files with liberty websphere?
2. Seems like it read the column name and the first line and then it encountered the exception. this is really odd. Could it be due to some character like `\r` or `\n` that was written in the file?

**Update**

I even tried it with an empty file and i get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a NumberFormatException when your handler is trying to convert your String values "col_name" and "some random text" to a byte array.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "col_name 
some random text,some random text2"
```

Simplest fix may be to change this

```
 @FormParam("csv") byte[] data
```

To this:

```
 @FormParam("csv") String[] data
```

Comment: by the way is there a way to read it line by line? now it is being read as an array of strings?

Comment: Are you able/interested in using `@FormParam("csv") File csvFile` to get the whole thing into a file on the server?